# Bump map causes strange shading

Tags: rendering, shaders, lighting, shadows

What is causing this strange shading when adding bump/normal maps?
This happens in the viewport and the final render.

See image below were the sun transitions into shadow.
It should be more smooth.

Blender v2.79

Cycles

HDRI lighting

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]


Bump map close-up:
[image]

Also, it seems that adding subdivions increases quality but at a great cost of performance.

Answer (score 1):

Given the image, and the fact that subdivisions help, I'm inclined to say that it's a terminator problem.
Sadly, it's a common problem on most ray/pathtracers, so your solutions are:

- Increase subdivisions.
- Increase light sizes. This will make shadows softer, and will mask the problem a bit.
- Use a non-tracer renderer (like Blender Internal or, maybe Eevee), that doesn't have this problem.